# FilterContainer in Elasticsearch NEST 5.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working on Elasticsearch migration from 1.7.1 to 5.0.
I fixed most of the issues in the code after upgrading to 5.0 but I couldn't figure out how to change ***FilterContainer*** to work in new version.

Below is my code

---

```
public static List<FilterContainer> GetPriceRangeFilters(SearchListCriteria criteria, out List<FilterContainer> additionalpricefilters)
    {
        var pricefilters = new List<FilterContainer>();
        additionalpricefilters = new List<FilterContainer>();
        if (criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MinimumPriceRange != null && criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MinimumPriceRange.Length > 0)
        {
            const string fieldName = "itemPrices.webPrice";
            pricefilters.Add((new FilterDescriptor<ItemSearchEntry>()).Query(a => a.Range(n => n.OnField(fieldName).GreaterOrEquals(criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MinimumPriceRange[0].ToString()).
                LowerOrEquals(criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MaximumPriceRange[0].ToString()))));
            for (var i = 1; i < criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MinimumPriceRange.Length; i++)
            {
                additionalpricefilters.Add((new FilterDescriptor<ItemSearchEntry>()).Query(a => a.Range(n => n.OnField(fieldName).
                    GreaterOrEquals(criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MinimumPriceRange[i].ToString()).LowerOrEquals(criteria.SearchGlobalSettings.MaximumPriceRange[i].ToString()))));
            }
        }
        return pricefilters;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`FilterContainer` no longer exists in NEST 2.0 onwards, [because filters and queries merged in Elasticsearch into queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#breaking_20_query_dsl_changes), with a *query* or *filter* context.

Where you would have used `FilterContainer`, use `QueryContainer` and then when adding to the search, pass the collection of `FilterContainer` into a `bool` query `filter` clause.